# How to create shortcut for Stored Procedure in SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQLSERVER 2008 R2. I have a procedure and want to run it manually to check information. I want to create a shortcut for that procedure so that by pressing the shortcut key, I can run the SP.
Is this possible using `SSMS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

```
extras -> options -> keyboard
```

You can add there your stored procedure name for a shortcut of your choice.

Comment: yes that i know but what if i have a parameterize procedure how can i implement there ?

Comment: There is no keyboard shortcut that also provides a prompt to specify parameters. The closest you'll get is a template or, in SQL Server 2012, the more powerful Snippet feature.